# <button> element not propagating events in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, firefox, jquery-events

I'm seeing issues in Firefox 4.0.1 where event propagation does not seem to be working the way I would expect. Let's say I have the following HTML:

```
<button>
    <input id='cb' type='checkbox' checked='true'>
    <span> foo</span>
</button>
```

and JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function(e) {
        console.log('got click: button');
        return true;
    });
    $("#cb").click(function(e) {
        console.log('got click: checkbox');
        return true;
    });
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/H7fp3/10/

This behaves as I would expect in Chrome (12), and Safari (5.0.5):

- Click on the *checkbox* produces: `got click: checkbox`, then `got click: button`
- Click on the *button* alone, produces: `got click: button`

However, in Firefox (4.0.1) both produce `got click: button` and do not alter the checkbox *checked* attribute. Am I missing something here? Is Firefox propagating button click events correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say Firefox is actually in the right here. According to the [W3C's validation tool](http://validator.w3.org/), `<input>` isn't allowed inside `<button>`.

Also, `checked="true"` should be `checked="checked"`, which might also be causing issues (or could potentially cause issues in other contexts).

Comment: I suspected that was the case. The problem is some libraries are zealously using jQueryUI buttons. I'm looking at you [DataTables ColVis](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/extras/ColVis/)